# Having Issues with the Kadmin being locked out and Active Directory in linux ftp and Kerberos

Tags: linux, active-directory, credentials, lock, kerberos

So I have a Linux FTP site that I am configuring, and I am picking up where a previous colleague of mine left off. The Ftp supposedly has Active Directory login, which seems to work for certain users in the workplace. However I cannot seem to login as the kadmin because it says that the initial credentials have been revoked. I am trying to figure out how to work and operate this kerberos system so that we can continue to use the Active Directory he was in the process of setting up, however he is no longer with us, and I am stuck in the middle of a puzzle. From my understanding we are supposed to create the KDC, and create a kadmin for the KDC who can add/remove users, and associate principals with them. However I do not know what the name of the KDC he set up is, How to unlock the kadmin account, and how to add a new admin user. Please note that I do have the root account access as that is the only thing he left me. Please Advise on how I can either unlock the current kadmin, or create a new one as I cannot move past this current step and it is the last thing holding up the release of this new FTP server!! Thanks !

Comment: Active Directory doesn't use the term 'kadmin' (and it generally refers to a management tool/program, not an account). What specifically are you trying to log into, via which software? Is the KDC / AD DC hosted somewhere else, or on the same computer?

Comment: So the current server I have is a red hat  FTP server, the KDC is on the same computer, the AD is hosted somewhere else. The issue is that Its a halfway functional project. I dont have access to the kadmin to add/remove principals that can be authenticated against the remote AD. also , im trying to log into the actual linux ftp server just via local login, but the way this system is set up it uses Kerberos to authenticate against the remote AD. which allows users to login to the local linux ftp site, with there AD credentials. hope that clears up some confusion?